# Accessing properties of an anonymous types in C#?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

Say I created an anonymous type for person that has name and birth date as properties:

```
var person = new{ Name = "Mike", BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 9, 2) };
```

then later on, decided to add a method that will return the age of the person.

```
var person = new { Name = "Mike", 
                   BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 9, 2), 
                   GetAge = new Func<int>(() => { return /* What? */; }) };
```

How do I access the property `BirthDate` so that I can compute the age? I tried using `this` but of course it didn't work.

Comment: Because anonymous type properties are readonly I see no point in doing that. You can just use `new DateTime(1990, 9, 2)` directly within `GetAge` property implementation and there will be no difference.

Comment: You can't, as far as I know.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I don't know when or why, but if presented with a situation in the future where I need to do this, what would I do?

Comment: @dpp Create appropriate class for it. Anonymous types are used only for simple and temporary storage of data. For everything else, you should create new type.

Comment: I'd rather create a new type for that

Comment: OT: There should really be a way to accept @JonSkeet 's comment as correct answer.

Comment: @Jon Wouldn't dynamic work?

Comment: It's a good question but there a clearly many ways around this by using other approaches... @newStackExchangeInstance no `dynamic` would not work here.

Comment: @Euphoric Marcin's comment would be a better candidate for the correct answer.

Comment: @Killercam I actually tried it with dynamic object before anonymous type, can't make it work either.

Comment: It is possible check out my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can't.  You will have to create a `Person` class to have such functionality:

```
    class Person {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public TimeSpan Age {
            get {
                // calculate Age
            }
        }
    }

    var person = new Person {
            Name = "Mike",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 9, 2))
    };
```

**Edit:** Another option is to create an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for `DateTime`:

```
    public static TimeSpan GetAge(this DateTime date) {
        // calculate Age
    }

    var person = new {
            Name = "Mike",
            BirthDate = new DateTime(1990, 9, 2))
    };

    TimeSpan age = person.BirthDate.GetAge();
```

Comment: I don't actually need a tutorial on how to declare a class and properties, I'm studying anonymous types and dynamic objects. Nevertheless, I appreciate everybody's help.

Comment: +1 for the extension method. Although, it will also add `GetAge` method to other `DateTime` objects.